# How to programmatically filter by property in Orchard in the ApplyFilter method of a Filter implementing IFilterProvider

Tags: nhibernate, orchardcms

**Simplified Model:**

```
public class GolfCourseDetailsPart : ContentPart<GolfCourseDetailsRecord>
{
  public bool ShowInHomePage {... //Get and Set using Retrieve and Store  methods
}
```

**Simplified Migrations:**

```
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("GolfCourse", gc => gc
     //...
     .WithPart(typeof(GolfCourseDetailsPart).Name)
);
```

I need to filter all items of type "GolfCourse" to get only the ones that have ShowInHomePage set to *true*.

**Filter:**

I have created a filter implementing the IFilterProvider interface and it returns all the GolfCourse content items but I couldn't get to filter by ShowInHomePage yet:

```
private void ApplyFilter(FilterContext context)
{
 context.Query = context.Query.Join(x=>x.ContentPartRecord(typeof(GolfCourseDetailsRecord))); 
}
```

How could I get to filter by the property ShowInHomePage??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, the only part missing is the `.Where` clause. In a HQL query it looks like this:

```
private void ApplyFilter(FilterContext context)
{
    context.Query = context
        .Query
        .Join(x => x.ContentPartRecord(typeof(GolfCourseDetailsRecord)))
        .Where(x => x.ContentPartRecord<GolfCourseDetailsRecord>(), g => g.Eq("ShowInHomePage", true));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you want to create an IFilterProvider? 
Those will be only useful if you want to have a customized filter available for query projections.

If you simply want to get filtered data programmatically then I would use Query method of ContentManager.

Here is a set of samples on how querying Orchard, I think it will be more useful for you than if I simply put here the query you need: https://orchardtrainingdemo.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Controllers/ContentsAdminController.cs

Comment: Hi Jersiovic. A custom filter for query projections is what I _guess_ I need. At the end what I want is to have a Projection Widget defined in code. I want all my CMS to be defined in code and, If I have to restore everything, I want it all to be set up just by enabling my module. But don't know what's the path to get to this point, so, I'm programmatically recreating the steps you would follow through the UI (but in code).
With _this filter_ I get a custom Filter in the filters list in UI and I can add it to a query. Next step would be creating a projection widget that uses that query...

Comment: I thought it is not a good idea to create a customized filter for only that purpose. You can use existing ones to do what you want (using Import-Export Bindings Feature).
Related of the idea of having all your CMS defined in code I usually prefer to have all my CMS defined in a recipe that is launched when the site is created, but that is another discussion :)

Comment: Maybe what you do is great and we just don't know how to control recipes. Our experience with recipes is that they're hard to manage and review. They're unpredictable and sometimes they just don't work or they do it partially. We may get to properly use them if we learn how to.